# BoltForms required fields, CSRF related

Tags: bolt-cms

On a BoltForms implementation I get

```
(my Dutch required fields warning)
```

while all required fields have been filled

and

```
This form should not contain extra fields.
```

With switched off CSRF protection, sending the form goes allright though, but I this is probably not a good idea for the long term. What goes wrong here?

Answer (score 0):

After some research: this turned out to be probably hosting-related. So if you run into similar problems, you might look into the hosting settings.